# Creating a table entry while using CarrierWaveDirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Is it possible to use something like CarrierWaveDirect to upload directly to S3 and still be able to gather some data on the files being uploaded?

For instance, is it possible to change the filename, and save the size in a table before/after the upload? I don't need to do any kind of manipulation to the file either (I was reading some documentation regarding the use of Resque).

I realize that this is a very novice question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, I found out that the S3 secure upload form that the hidden field `success_action_redirect` returns so params on the uploaded file.